# What do I have to do to redirect on same page's controller after clicking on Action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Name",new { id = item.Id })`

controller

`[HttpPost]`

`public ActionResult Action_Result_Name(Model_Name Obj_Model, string Add, int id)
        {}`

When I click on actionlink I want to redirect in Same page contoller.
But when I put ("int id") in actionResult form it won't go into controller for the first time

Comment: so your controller name is EditController? @Html.ActionLink(string linkText,MethodName, controllerName,htmlAttributes)

Please provide more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ActionLink will create is a HTTP GET and your controller's action is decorated with HTTPPOST attribute.

What you should be using is a PRG pattern: POST-REDIRECT-GET.

For example: If you have a page for list of products and an edit (GET) action to edit a single product. Your View should have a form that posts the edited product to a HTTP POST action and then within that action you redirect to a GET:

Product Controller Actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    //Get product by id
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var product = productRepository.GetProductById(id);
    return View(product);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    //Get product by id
    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var product = productRepository.GetProductById(id);
    return View(product);
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToActionResult Edit(Product product)
{
    //validation checks should happen first
    //if model state is valid then save product

    var productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    var productId = productRepository.Save(product);

    return RedirectToAction("GetProduct", new {id = productId});
}
```

EditProduct View:

```
@model Product
<form action="/product/edit" method="POST">
@*
Place HTML to show your HTML edit controls
to allow users to edit Product values
*@
</form>
```

There are a lot of things that are basic here. You may want to make sure you use a DI framework like Ninject, StructureMap etc so that all your repositories. But it at least gives you a general idea.

Hope this helps.